# Preload assemblies: referenced, unreferenced, not loaded until they are needed

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, assemblies, preload

I would like to create a splash screen that shows loading of individual assembly, before showing the main form.

I am doing preload by:

```
Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
foreach (AssemblyName an in a.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    Assembly.Load(an);
}
```

I have two problems:

**Problem 1:**

Some assembly are loaded after the preload, even they are not included in the references:

> 'x.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'x.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

I can get around this problem by connecting the assembly to the reference but I do not want to do that since the compiler does not force me.

**Problem 2:**

I am using telerik RadPadeView. On secound page i have ElementHost control that contain WPF Gantt from Telerik (Main application is WinForm) . After the show the main window, I click on the second tab to see the gantt. And at this point, additional assemby loaded.

> 'x.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>
> 'x.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The **question** is, how to preload all assemblies:

1. Referenced
2. Unreferenced (Problem 1)
3. Not loaded until they are needed (Problem 2)

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly.Load
```

Is all you need to load assemblys from either already references types or by filepath.
See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(v=vs.110).aspx)