# Preloading Referenced Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, preloading

I've got a rather large (and growing) application that uses [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/) and subsequently the TinyIoC library. Each of the modules are broken out into individual projects, along with my data models, so my project structure looks sort-of like this:

```
Solution
  |- NancyHost
  |- DataModels
  |- Modules.Common
  |- Modules.Dashboard
  |- Modules.Security
  |- Repositories
```

The issue that I'm having is TinyIoC has an `AutoRegister` event that is supposed to go through the current AppDomain and register all the "register-able" types. This is great except that on startup the assemblies are not yet loaded into the app domain since it uses DI to resolve types.

As a work-around I've come up with classes like this:

```
public static class RepositoryInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {

    }
}
```

Which I then call from the `Main` on startup, but I don't really like that approach since it requires me to make a dummy initializer class for each linked assembly. I could also do something like:

```
GC.KeepAlive(typeof(ReferencedAssembly.SomeType));
```

But again, that requires me to add that same directive for each referenced assembly.

I thought I remember something about a hard-binding attribute you could apply to the assembly that would pre-load a referenced assembly? I can't find anything on it but I swear it was there.

I also tried this:

```
    static void Preload()
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var dllFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.dll"))
        {
            types.AddRange(Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(dllFile).GetTypes());
        }

        var assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

        //assemblies does not contain all referenced assemblies
    }
```

Because I read something about using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` that would cause the DLL to load, but this gives me an exception about having to preload other referenced DLL's to be able to reflect the types (like `System.Core`).

So the question is, how can I preload my referenced assemblies without using explicit references to the types they contain? Please note that `Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` only contains the **loaded** assemblies, not all the referenced ones.

This is somewhat duplicate, but not any help: [Preload assemblies: referenced, unreferenced, not loaded until they are needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023494/preload-assemblies-referenced-unreferenced-not-loaded-until-they-are-needed)

**Edit**
Here is a version with `Assembly.Load`:

```
    static void Preload()
    {
        string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (var dllFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.dll"))
        {
            assemblies.Add(Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName() { CodeBase = dllFile }));
            //Also tried Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(dllFile)), same effect
        }

        var refAssemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
    }
```

It does load the assemblies into the `assemblies` list, but does not cause them to be loaded into the current app domain. (`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()` returns the same before and after the `Preload` call).

Comment: `Assembly.Load` is what you actually want.

Comment: @SLaks How do I load it into the current app domain? All the `Assembly.Load` overloads take an assembly name, assuming I don't have all of them hard-coded, how do I figure out which ones are referenced by the executable?

Comment: Just construct an `AssemblyName` from each DLL filename.

Comment: @SLaks Am I supposed to do something special with the returned assembly? The `Assembly.Load(byte[])` says that it gets loaded into the callers app domain, but (see my edit), it doesn't look like it does since the call to `GetReferencedAssemblies()` is the same before and after `Preload`.

Comment: `GetReferencedAssemblies()` returns all references _that your assembly uses_.  Unused references are stripped at compile-time.  Loading assemblies will never change the result of `GetReferencedAssemblies()`.